# ProcessStartInfo run exe in PATH envirionment variable

Tags: c#, filenotfoundexception, processstartinfo

I'm trying to run an exe using ProcessStartInfo. The problem is I only want to specify the exe name, and add the executable path to the PATH environment variable in Windows. When I try to run my application I got a FileNotFoundException. Everything works fine when I start the process with the full name. Any ideas?

--
Edit: Thanks for the comments, Ill give an example to make it more clear:

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("example.exe");
```

I added the path of example.exe in the Windows Envirionment PATH variable manually, but still my application can't start the process example.exe

Comment: do you want to add it programmatically to the path environment variable?

Comment: Have you re-started the application after changing the environment variable?

Comment: Log out and log back in to ensure all processes, including VS, Explorer and the VS hosting process use the modified environment variable.

Comment: Thanks Hans, problem solved. Didn't know I had to close VS as well (in fact I restarted my machine today and it worked).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx) and [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx) that are on the [`Environment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) class.

```
var currentPathVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path");
var newPathVariable = currentPathVariable + ";another path";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path", newPathVariable);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I meant. I made it more clear by adding an example in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sub key in the key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths** in the registry.

Have a look at [Registering Applications Using the App Paths sub key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#appPaths).